# manejo de errores en asp

Tags: asp.net, asp

[image: Solicito su ayuda para poder manejar los errores de este tipo, para que no aparesca informacion que pueda ser utilizada de mala manera, es decir me gustaria saber como puedo hacer que al aparecer este tipo de errores se deje un mensaje de error mas personalizado, ej " error en la consulta, o nose "]

Solicito su ayuda para poder manejar los errores de este tipo, para que no aparesca informacion que pueda ser utilizada de mala manera, es decir me gustaria saber como puedo hacer que al aparecer este tipo de errores se deje un mensaje de error mas personalizado, ej " error en la consulta", para las paginas 4xx y 5xx

Answer (score 4):

Según veo en tu código, estás utilizando asp clásico, con lo cual, para el manejo de errores deberías utilizar "On Error Resume Next "

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
<%
On Error Resume Next
'AQUÍ IRÍA EL CÓDIGO SUSCEPTIBLE DE QUE SE PRODUZCA UN ERROR
'Si se produce un error  
If err.Number <> 0 Then 
Response.Write "Código de error = " & err.Number & "; descripción del error = " & err.Description   'mostramos en pantalla el código de error  y descripción
End If
%>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar este codigo:

```
try{
//codigo...
}catch (Exception $e){
echo 'se ha producido un error: '.$e->getMessage();
//si no quieres mostrar el error
echo 'se ha producido un error.';
}
```

Comment: ese codigo es PHP????

Comment: si es php aunque se puede utilizar en mas lenguajes de programación adaptándolo un poco